# Avoid dropping nulls to run function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following outlier detection function:

```
id = np.linspace(1,200,200)

days = [350.0, 641.0, 389.0, 130.0, 344.0, 92.0, 392.0, 51.0, 28.0, 358.0, 
        309.0, 64.0, 380.0, 491.0, 332.0, 410.0, 66.0, 435.0, 156.0, 294.0, 
        75.0, 284.0, 105.0, 34.0, 50.0, 155.0, 427.0, 327.0, 116.0, 97.0, 
        274.0, 315.0, 99.0, 70.0, 62.0, 241.0, 397.0, 50.0, 41.0, 231.0, 
        238.0, 216.0, 105.0, 36.0, 192.0, 38.0, 122.0, 37.0, 236.0, 175.0, 
        138.0, 146.0, 125.0, 144.0, 166.0, 19.0, 155.0, 130.0, 54.0, 120.0, 
        65.0, 95.0, 158.0, 92.0, 65.0, 52.0, 91.0, 67.0, 38.0, 72.0, 36.0, 
        14.0, 74.0, 155.0, 503.0, 110.0, 338.0, 444.0, 408.0, 107.0, 214.0, 
        291.0, 91.0, 277.0, 96.0, 325.0, 154.0, 314.0, 377.0, 147.0, 48.0, 
        224.0, 75.0, 268.0, 135.0, 177.0, 133.0, 306.0, 187.0, 145.0, 353.0, 
        148.0, 182.0, 95.0, 82.0, None, 143.0, 79.0, 168.0, 141.0, 224.0, 82.0,
        202.0, 107.0, 169.0, 153.0, 156.0, 79.0, 49.0, 126.0, 44.0, 67.0, 64.0, 
        102.0, 74.0, 56.0, 102.0, 285.0, 386.0, 176.0, 106.0, 6.0, 322.0, 72.0, 
        192.0, 429.0, 101.0, 159.0, 168.0, 319.0, 178.0, 323.0, 295.0, 151.0, 
        286.0, 93.0, 336.0, 252.0, 111.0, 49.0, 113.0, 214.0, 230.0, 77.0,
        192.0, 219.0, 166.0, 72.0, 143.0, 166.0, 140.0, 191.0, 113.0, 83.0, 
        41.0, 28.0, 84.0, 78.0, 28.0, 202.0, 223.0, 188.0, 238.0, 212.0, 133.0, 77.0,
        235.0, 212.0, 243.0, 176.0, 167.0, 69.0, 108.0, 11.0, 35.0, 63.0, 38.0, 445.0,
        111.0, 135.0, 143.0, 70.0, 143.0, 77.0, 22.0, 222.0, 444.0, 321.0, 1.0, 234.0]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ids': id,
     'days': days
    })

def get_bounds(df, serie): 
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(df[serie], [25, 75]) 
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1 
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5) 
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5) 
    return lower_bound, upper_bound 

lower_bound, upper_bound = get_bounds(df,'days') #####!
print(upper_bound)
df = df.loc[df['days'] < upper_bound].sort_values('days') #remove outliers
print(df)
```

This throws an error however if I change the row with `#####!` to:
`lower_bound, upper_bound = get_bounds(df.dropna(subset=['days']),'days')` then it runs without a problem.

However, some functions that reference `df` require the nulls that I am forced to drop in order to run the outlier definition properly. Can you please assist in changing it to not force me to drop nulls in order to run the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.nanpercentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html#numpy.nanpercentile). This ignores `nan` values while taking percentiles. So the code within your custom function should be:

```
quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.nanpercentile(df[serie], [25, 75])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas DataFrames have their own version of `numpy.percentile` that handles NaN values gracefully, [`DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html). Use that instead.

```
quartile_1, quartile_3 = df[serie].quantile([0.25, 0.75])
```

Right from the docs:

> Return values at the given quantile over requested axis, a la `numpy.percentile`.